# Are there Gems/Plugins to provide nice styling for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, styling

I'm a developer and not a designer. I'm not looking for something fancy just basic but nice styling.

I used [Nifty Generator](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) before which generates some styling but I was looking for something different. Maybe different Themes that automatically styles forms/colors of the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme

Web App Theme is skinnable, you can download additional themes for it too.  There are examples and links on the github page.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Twitter Bootstrap for Rails gem is a great way to build apps that look professionally designed.  Built by @mdo and @fat at Twitter they made it so they could create great looking rapid prototypes.  You can learn more about Bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Highly recommended.